# Uninstalled Ruby.Frameworks on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, ruby

In an attempt to create a clean Ruby slate for myself, I uninstalled RVM, rbenv (yeah, I had both installed, whoops), Gem, Bundler, and the pre-installed version of Ruby. I didn't realize the chaos this would cause.

Only after I did this did I remember that Homebrew is a Ruby script. I decided to install RVM to install Ruby so that Homewbrew would work again, only to find out that RVM relies on Homebrew! I then compiled the latest Ruby from source, but apparently, Homebrew's script tries to call the built-in Ruby. I modified the Homebrew source on my machine to see if that would work (now calling `/usr/bin/env ruby`), and even though *runs* now, things are definitely messed up.

I got my computer back in the 10.5 days, no longer have the install disc, and have upgraded to 10.7 and 10.8 through the App Store, so I'm not sure how to get my old Ruby back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any backups, you could also copy Ruby.framework from a VM. If you can't redownload the 10.8 installer from App Store, there are torrents for 10.8 disk images.

You could also reinstall OS X from the recovery partition. The UI doesn't make it very clear, but it just upgrades or repairs the current installation, like upgrading from 10.7 to 10.8. I have done it twice so far and it solved multiple issues both times.

Or wait until Apple releases 10.9 or a developer preview of it.

Some system files can also be copied from BaseSystem.dmg after mounting it with `diskutil mount "Recovery HD"; hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg`. It doesn't include Ruby.framework though.